# Report display between start and end date

Tags: sql-server

```
Select distinct 
    DMA.EmpID as "Employe ID:", 
    DMA.LASTNAME as "Last Name:",
    DMA.FirstName as "First Name:",
    SM.CDU_Academic_Rank_1of2 as "CDU Rank",
    DMA.AnnualPay as "Salary All:", 
    DMA.Class as "Emp Class",
    DMA.[Department Name] as "Department:",
    DMA.Activity as "Account:",
    DMA.Effort_percentage/100 as "Effort", 
    DMA.Activitypay as "Amount", 
    DMA.ActivityStart as "Start Date",
    DMA.ActivityEnd as "End Date", 
    SM.COM,
    SM.COSH, 
    SM.SON, 
    KWAS.ActivityPayInactive
from 
    dbo.DMActivitysalary AS DMA 
    inner JOIN vw_KW_Shay_Main AS SM ON DMA.EmpID = SM.Employee_ID
    inner join vw_KW_Activity_Salary_ODBC as KWAS on DMA.EmpID = KWAS.EmpID
where 
    DMA.[Department Name] in (@Dept) 
    AND DMA.[Effort_Percentage] in (@Effort) 
    AND DMA.Activity in (@Account) 
    AND (KWAS.ActivityPayInactive = 'NO') 
    AND where DMA.EmpID between DMA.ActivityStart in (@StartDate) 
    AND DMA.ActivityEnd in (@EndDate)
order by 
    DMA.ActivityEnd
```

Hello,

I wrote the report that accepted 4 param but not sure how to get the result to display between @startdate and @enddate of my param.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a `BETWEEN` syntax that you might be able to use against both `DMA.ActivityStart` and `DMA.ActivityEnd` but that brings up other questions such as: "_can ActivityEnd have NULL values_".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First: Change double quote `"` by single quote `'` or brackets `[]`

```
DMA.EmpID as "Employe ID:" -->  DMA.EmpID as [Employe ID:]
```

Then, there is an error in your sentence:

```
AND where DMA.EmpID between DMA.ActivityStart in (@StartDate) 
AND DMA.ActivityEnd in (@EndDate)
```

Cannot user WHERE twice, change it by;

```
AND DMA.ActivityStart >= (@StartDate) 
AND DMA.ActivityEnd < (@EndDate)
```

Take care with time part of DateTime:

```
'2017-01-01 00:00:01' > '2017-01-01'
```